# Proper way to download mutilple files from server in android

Tags: android, service

I want to download multiple `apk` files from server using background service but confused about implementation

What could be the proper way to do that?
Should I create a service and download these apks using downloadmanager
or should I use service with libs like volley or asyncHttpClient to download apks?

and one more thing that i want is, every 1 hr i want to check for any new apks are available on server

Should i use handler that post every 1hr or should use alarm manager to do that

please help

Comment: just use an IntentService. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933257/android-best-practice-for-retrying-intentservice/30169847#30169847) is a post.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to download the files is to use `DownloadManager`, if it fits your needs.

For the second problem you shouldn't use handler, as your app may be killed by the system. So, use `AlarmManager`, but note, that after reboot all alarms are cleared.

Comment: I can start service as sticky

Comment: To keep your app alive? It won't help. It's easier to use `AlarmManager`.